# can a django app in development be used directly onto production

Tags: django

Being a newbie to django and python, i managed to create a small project.
I understand this way is the development phase.

If i wish to put this work from development phase into production, would Django's inbuilt server capable enough to handle the requests? Is it not mandatory to keep development and production separate?

Comment: Django does not server *static* and *media* files in production since it is likely *unsafe* (and inefficient), so you will need to configure the webserver (like nginx/apache) to handle these. Furthermore often there is something in between that can spawn "Django processes" to handle multiple requests concurrently. So unless security is not important at all, and nor is performance, no you can not simply deploy it *as is*. It is probably also better to take care about this *before* the load is growing.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem, i will begin to read apache then. Thanks again.

Comment: you can take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/

Comment: Nice!!! I will read that as well then.... thanks again @WillemVanOnsem  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

No, I would suggest reading the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver, it is fairly strong in not using it for production.

This may also be helpful in deploying your first django app: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/